# Data Mining from HTML

Tags: php, html, database, extract, data-mining

I am wondering if there is a script I can write that writes all the available options from a `<td class>` html file.  I know I could just copy and past the source code but I really want to learn to data-mine.  Here is the code of the table.  I am learning about databases and PHP and I need to generate a course roster and I don't want to take the easy way out and copy&paste. similarly I want to then go to each department and get a list of courses.

Here is the source code:

```
    <td class="dedefault" colspan="7">
<select id="subj_id" size="1" name="sel_subj">
<option selected="" value="%">not selected </option>
<option value="AA">AA - Allied Arts </option>
<option value="AAA">AAA - Architecture & Allied Arts </option>
<option value="AAAP">AAAP - Historic Preservation </option>
<option value="AAD">AAD - Arts & Administration </option>
<option value="ACTG">ACTG - Accounting </option>
<option value="AEIS">AEIS - Acad Eng for Intl Stu </option>
<option value="AFR">AFR - African Studies </option>
<option value="AIM">AIM - Applied Information Management </option>
<option value="ANTH">ANTH - Anthropology </option>
<option value="ARB">ARB - Arabic </option>
<option value="ARCH">ARCH - Architecture </option>
<option value="ARH">ARH - Art History </option>
<option value="ART">ART - Art </option>
<option value="ARTC">ARTC - Ceramics </option>
<option value="ARTD">ARTD - Digital Arts </option>
<option value="ARTF">ARTF - Fibers </option>
<option value="ARTM">ARTM - Metalsmithing & Jewelry </option>
<option value="ARTO">ARTO - Photography </option>
<option value="ARTP">ARTP - Painting </option>
<option value="ARTR">ARTR - Printmaking </option>
<option value="ARTS">ARTS - Sculpture </option>
<option value="ASIA">ASIA - Asian Studies </option>
<option value="ASL">ASL - American Sign Language </option>
<option value="ASTR">ASTR - Astronomy </option>
<option value="BA">BA - Business Administration </option>
<option value="BE">BE - Business Environment </option>
<option value="BI">BI - Biology </option>
<option value="CARC">CARC - Career Center </option>
<option value="CAS">CAS - College of Arts & Sciences </option>
<option value="CDS">CDS - Communication Disorders & Sci </option>
<option value="CFT">CFT - Couples & Family Therapy </option>
<option value="CH">CH - Chemistry </option>
<option value="CHN">CHN - Chinese </option>
<option value="CHNF">CHNF - Chinese Flagship </option>
<option value="CINE">CINE - Cinema Studies </option>
<option value="CIS">CIS - Computer & Information Science </option>
<option value="CIT">CIT - Computer Information Tech </option>
<option value="CLAS">CLAS - Classics </option>
<option value="COLT">COLT - Comparative Literature </option>
<option value="CPSY">CPSY - Counseling Psychology </option>
<option value="CRES">CRES - Conflict & Dispute Resolution </option>
<option value="CRWR">CRWR - Creative Writing </option>
<option value="CSCH">CSCH - College Scholars </option>
<option value="DAN">DAN - Dance Professional </option>
<option value="DANC">DANC - Dance Activity </option>
<option value="DANE">DANE - Danish </option>
<option value="DIST">DIST - Distance Education </option>
<option value="DSC">DSC - Decision Sciences </option>
<option value="EALL">EALL - East Asian Lang & Literature </option>
<option value="EC">EC - Economics </option>
<option value="EDLD">EDLD - Educational Leadership </option>
<option value="EDST">EDST - Education Studies </option>
<option value="EDUC">EDUC - Education </option>
<option value="ENG">ENG - English </option>
<option value="ENVS">ENVS - Environmental Studies </option>
<option value="ES">ES - Ethnic Studies </option>
<option value="ESC">ESC - Community Internship Program </option>
<option value="EURO">EURO - European Studies </option>
<option value="FHS">FHS - Family & Human Services </option>
<option value="FIN">FIN - Finance </option>
<option value="FINN">FINN - Finnish </option>
<option value="FLR">FLR - Folklore </option>
<option value="FR">FR - French </option>
<option value="FSEM">FSEM - Freshman Seminar </option>
<option value="GEOG">GEOG - Geography </option>
<option value="GEOL">GEOL - Geology </option>
<option value="GER">GER - German </option>
<option value="GRK">GRK - Greek </option>
<option value="GSS">GSS - General Social Science </option>
<option value="HBRW">HBRW - Hebrew </option>
<option value="HC">HC - Honors College </option>
<option value="HIST">HIST - History </option>
<option value="HPHY">HPHY - Human Physiology </option>
<option value="HUM">HUM - Humanities </option>
<option value="IARC">IARC - Interior Architecture </option>
<option value="INTL">INTL - International Studies </option>
<option value="IST">IST - Interdisciplinary Studies </option>
<option value="ITAL">ITAL - Italian </option>
<option value="J">J - Journalism </option>
<option value="JDST">JDST - Judaic Studies </option>
<option value="JGS">JGS - Japanese Global Scholars </option>
<option value="JPN">JPN - Japanese </option>
<option value="KRN">KRN - Korean </option>
<option value="LA">LA - Landscape Architecture </option>
<option value="LAS">LAS - Latin American Studies </option>
<option value="LAT">LAT - Latin </option>
<option value="LAW">LAW - Law </option>
<option value="LEAD">LEAD - Leadership Development </option>
<option value="LERC">LERC - Labor Educ & Research Center </option>
<option value="LIB">LIB - Library </option>
<option value="LING">LING - Linguistics </option>
<option value="LT">LT - Language Teaching </option>
<option value="MATH">MATH - Mathematics </option>
<option value="MDVL">MDVL - Medieval Studies </option>
<option value="MGMT">MGMT - Management </option>
<option value="MIL">MIL - Military Science </option>
<option value="MKTG">MKTG - Marketing </option>
<option value="MUE">MUE - Music Education </option>
<option value="MUJ">MUJ - Music Jazz Studies </option>
<option value="MUP">MUP - Music Performance </option>
<option value="MUS">MUS - Music </option>
<option value="NORW">NORW - Norwegian </option>
<option value="OIMB">OIMB - Oregon Inst of Marine Biology </option>
<option value="OLIS">OLIS - Oregon Ldrship Sustainability </option>
<option value="PD">PD - Product Design </option>
<option value="PDX">PDX - UO Portland Programs </option>
<option value="PEAE">PEAE - PE Aerobics </option>
<option value="PEAQ">PEAQ - PE Aquatics </option>
<option value="PEAS">PEAS - PE SCUBA </option>
<option value="PEC">PEC - PE Certification </option>
<option value="PEF">PEF - PE Fitness </option>
<option value="PEI">PEI - PE Individual Activities </option>
<option value="PEIA">PEIA - PE Intercollegiate Athletics </option>
<option value="PEL">PEL - PE Leadership </option>
<option value="PEMA">PEMA - PE Martial Arts </option>
<option value="PEMB">PEMB - PE Mind-Body </option>
<option value="PEOL">PEOL - PE Outdoor Pursuits - Land </option>
<option value="PEOW">PEOW - PE Outdoor Pursuits - Water </option>
<option value="PERS">PERS - PE Racquet Sports </option>
<option value="PERU">PERU - PE Running </option>
<option value="PETS">PETS - PE Team Sports </option>
<option value="PEW">PEW - PE Weight Training </option>
<option value="PHIL">PHIL - Philosophy </option>
<option value="PHYS">PHYS - Physics </option>
<option value="PORT">PORT - Portuguese </option>
<option value="PPPM">PPPM - Planning Public Policy Mgmt </option>
<option value="PS">PS - Political Science </option>
<option value="PSY">PSY - Psychology </option>
<option value="REES">REES - Russ & East European Studies </option>
<option value="REL">REL - Religious Studies </option>
<option value="RL">RL - Romance Languages </option>
<option value="RUSS">RUSS - Russian </option>
<option value="SAPP">SAPP - Substance Abuse Prev Prog </option>
<option value="SBUS">SBUS - Sports Business </option>
<option value="SCAN">SCAN - Scandinavian </option>
<option value="SERV">SERV - Service Learning </option>
<option value="SOC">SOC - Sociology </option>
<option value="SPAN">SPAN - Spanish </option>
<option value="SPED">SPED - Special Education </option>
<option value="SPSY">SPSY - School Psychology </option>
<option value="SWAH">SWAH - Swahili </option>
<option value="SWED">SWED - Swedish </option>
<option value="TA">TA - Theater Arts </option>
<option value="TLC">TLC - Univ Teaching & Learning Ctr </option>
<option value="WGS">WGS - Women's & Gender Studies </option>
<option value="WR">WR - Writing </option>
```

Here is the basics of the department course list:

```
<tr>
<td style="font-weight:bolder">
<a href="/Classes/index.php?course=cis110">CIS 110 Fluency with Information Technology</a>
</td> </tr>
```

Comment: check file_get_contents(); and preg_match(); functions. With both you can do what you want to do.

Comment: Oh i didn't see your comment.  I'm slowly understnading it but it seems just what i need.  Thank you!  I assume use file_get_contents("URL)" preg_match(option value=") (note i just looked it up briefly i will do more research)

Comment: For example you can do it between `<select>` and `</select>` then you can get all the option list

Answer (score 0):

Typically whenever you're retrieving data from a database in order to display information in the UI, it's best to avoid copy and paste "inheritance". Instead you might want to look into template based data binding.
What specific approach to use is dependent on the technology you're using.
In the above case it looks like it would make send to bind your dropdown to a data source

Comment: The scope of the project is to create a menu which you select the department and then select the course.  I honestly don't know what "template based data binding" means.  My brain keeps thinking in queries like SELECT *From dedefault.  I really want to learn not copy&paste because i feel that's cheating and I want to do it in coding.